# Could a soldier wearing TALOS armor use a .950 caliber rifle without a bipod?

Tags: warfare, weapons

Self explanatory. Here's the monster:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/.950_JDJ

And here's TALOS:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/TALOS_(uniform)

Assuming a combination of carefully administered adrenaline, gene therapy to increase mitochondria levels and a futuristic exoskeleton similar to TALOS, could a soldier with x5-10 normal human strength wield a .950 caliber rifle without injuring themselves or losing their grip on the gun due to recoil?

Comment: Talos is only a plan / prototype, so it's hard to know.

Comment: If you wear a powered armor the bipod is no bother. If you carry a 50kg rifle just take the bipod along.

Answer (score 1):

Although the precision of TALOS type wearable exoskeleton is yet unknown, it would *probably* be insufficiently precise for accurately shooting a very high powered round like the .950 While it can be said confidently that it would provide the user with enough power to carry the weapon, aiming and recoil management are quite delicate matters which not only involve the strong biceps and triceps muscles but also the wrists and fingers. This implies that a person wearing a TALOS type exoskeleton would be able to *shoot* a .950 caliber rifle, the *accuracy* of the shot would be very low as compared to a bipod rest and shooting in a laying position.